# Calculate Standard Deviation on a List of List that includes strings on some columns

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the standard deviation of a lists of lists but not on all 'columns' of the list since some are numbers (middle columns). So I would skip those.

```
param_data = [["a", 2, 3, 6, 7, "b"],
              ["c", 6, 7, 8, 2, "d"],
              ["e", 5, 6, 8, 1, "f"]]
```

Expected results is:

```
params = [std.dev(2, 6, 5),
          std.dev(3, 7, 6),
          std.dev(6, 8, 8),
          std.dev(7, 2, 1)]
```

Note: not evaluating the standard deviation because it is not relevant to the question, just expressed that would be evaluated.
I tried using zip(*param_data) but cannot figure out how to only zip columns 1-4.

Comment: Do you have data that specifies which columns to use? If so, what is it? If not, how shall they be detected?

Comment: As with most problems in programming, this becomes easier to solve if you break it up into smaller parts. You have a list of lists where each inner list is a row (row-major). You want to [traverse the "2d list" in column-major order](/q/70209294/843953), [check that they are all integers](/q/8964191/843953), and [find the standard deviation](/q/15389768/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with better error handling:

```
from statistics import stdev
from numbers import Number

def resilient_stdevs(columns):
    cols = list(zip(*columns))
    for c in cols:
        if isinstance(c[0], Number):
            if not all(isinstance(x, Number) for x in c):
                raise TypeError("Cannot compute stdev of mixed types in a single column: got " + str(c))
        if not isinstance(c[0], Number):
            if not all(not isinstance(x, Number) for x in c):
                raise TypeError("Cannot compute stdev of mixed types in a single column: got " + str(c))
    return [stdev(xs) for xs in cols if isinstance(xs[0], (int, float))]

param_data = [["a", 2, "s", 6, 7, "b"],["c", 6, 4, 8, 2, "d"], ["e", 5, 6, 8, 1, "f"]]

print(resilient_stdevs(param_data))
```

This crashes (as it should) with a clear error message:

```
line 12, in resilient_stdevs
    raise TypeError("Cannot compute stdev of mixed types in a single column: got " + str(c))
TypeError: Cannot compute stdev of mixed types in a single column: got ('s', 4, 6)
```

---

You can use `list(zip(*param_data))` to transpose and `isinstance` to check the types, this works wherever the string columns are, even in the middle or if you have more of them:

```
from statistics import stdev

param_data = [["a", 2, 3, 6, 7, "b"],["c", 6, 7, 8, 2, "d"], ["e", 5, 6, 8, 1, "f"]]

cols = list(zip(*param_data))

params = [stdev(xs) for xs in cols if isinstance(xs[0], (int, float))]

print(params)
```

Output:

```
[2.0816659994661326, 2.0816659994661326, 1.1547005383792515, 3.2145502536643185]
```

Comment: This crashes if a column is mixed with strings and numbers

Comment: Marking this one as answer because it is more resilient to changes in column count and positions.

Comment: @chepox glad you liked it. I have just now also improved it with better error handling

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
from statistics import stdev

param_data = [["a", 2, 3, 6, 7, "b"],
              ["c", 6, 7, 8, 2, "d"],
              ["e", 5, 6, 8, 1, "f"]]

params = []
for column in zip(*param_data):
    try:
        params.append(stdev(column))
    except TypeError:
        pass

print(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to get the corresponding elements, and then use `zip`.

```py
from statistics import stdev

param_data = [["a", 2, 3, 6, 7, "b"],["c", 6, 7, 8, 2, "d"], ["e", 5, 6, 8, 1, "f"]]

elements = [x[1:5] for x in param_data]
print([stdev(x) for x in zip(*elements)])
```

This assumes that the numbers are always in that 1:5 slice; if that's not the case, we'll need more information.

Comment: We already have the information about stripping off first and last, just use negative indexing, i.e. `x[1:-1]`, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497971/how-can-i-slice-out-the-last-and-first-characters-of-a-string-in-python).

Comment: @metatoaster I don't see that stated. I only see "middle columns" and "columns 1-4".

Comment: @KellyBundy eh, "middle columns" with the context implied that. Though I can see why others might think I read too much into those two words. Nonetheless providing both did make the requirement ambiguous, doesn't hurt to provide both, OP did clarify the specific limitation of their solution.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Columns are fixed for my application. So the answer from metatoaster is spot on.

Comment: Application has fixed column count and positions. So metatoaster's idea works for my case.